# play sounds over ssh

Tags: ssh, audio, pulse-audio, x11-forwarding

Is there any way to play audio files through ssh ?

I set up the x11 forwarding , to view images , videos(without Audio) , but the problem is that I want to play sounds through ssh , since the x11 forwarding does not support the AUDIO ,
I have used the pulseAudio , but still it does not forward the audio through the ssh.

Are there any other possibilities to play sounds ?
Or is there any ways or technic to play sounds on a remote server which has no desktop environment?

I would be appreciate any replies .

Comment: [`xpra`](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/#about) claims [it can to do it](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/blob/master/docs/Features/Audio.md). It can use SSH as transport. I haven't tested, hence just a comment. Note the main purpose of `xpra` is to be "screen for X", forwarding audio is just one of its features.

Answer (score 2):

> i have used the pulseAudio , but still it does not forward the audio through the ssh .

It kind does, if you forward the PulseAudio connection through SSH. This needs to be done manually; there is no equivalent to the built-in `ssh -X` option for X11, although if your SSH client and server versions are recent enough, then you can at least use the `-R` option for generic forwarding.

The socket location is usually `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native` (or `/run/user/$UID/pulse/native`) – beware that if your UID is different between client and server, the path will also be different. For example, if your *remote* UID is 1003, you might use:

```
local$ ssh -R /run/user/1003/pulse/native:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native myserver
myserver$ pactl info
```

(The syntax is `-R <remote>:<local>`.)

Alternatively, specify a custom path:

```
local$ ssh -R /tmp/mypulse:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native myserver
myserver$ export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/mypulse
myserver$ pactl info
```

Note that PulseAudio, very much like X11, has network support and an "authentication" requirement. For X11, the SSH client handles this automatically; for PulseAudio, it *might* work automatically with help from X11 (using pax11publish), but if not, then you will need to manually transfer `~/.config/pulse/cookie` from your local system to the remote system (where the X11/PA clients are), e.g. using `scp`.

Also, since this transfers uncompressed PCM audio, it'll require far more bandwidth than typical audio streams. (Which is really the same situation as X11 forwarding, which transfers uncompressed bitmaps...) You might need the `ssh -C` (compress) option in addition.

As an additional complication, in some Linux distributions, "PulseAudio" is actually emulated by the newer PipeWire, which has its own protocol but also speaks PA. Fortunately it behaves like a regular PulseAudio server; the socket and cookie paths are the same.

All other alternatives will be pretty much the same: even if it's not PulseAudio, it still needs to be some sort of client/server protocol that can be forwarded through SSH in much the same way.